# Send Concurrent HTTP Requests From Array In Springboot

Tags: spring-boot

I have an array of objects that i need to send to an endpoint. I am currently looping through the array and sending the requests one by one. The issue is that i now have over 35,000 requests to be made, and i need to update the database with the response.In my limited knowledge of springboot , i am not aware of any method i can use to send the 35,000 requests at once (without looping through one by one).

Is the best method to use still employing looping but utilize asynchronous calls, or is there a method that i can use to send the 35,000 http requests at once?..i just need a pointer because i am not aware how threads can be used, since this is already an array and each element needs to be sent.

Thank you

Comment: Send the array in 1 request instead of multiple requests. Unless your endpoint doesn't support multiple elements then you have no other choice sending them one-by-one. Although you could parallelize it by using multiple threads.

Comment: The endpoint does not accept multiple

Comment: you can do Async request using spring boot? but at the same time need to know load that API can accept (like tps)? @ewom2468

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first off 35,000 at a time of, well, anything, is a bad idea.

However, if you look in to the [Java ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), this gives you the ability to fill a queue with tasks, and then each task will be performed by a thread taken from a thread pool. As the threads complete, the service pulls another request from the queue and handles that. So, you simply provide a Runnable that performs your web requests, create an Adequately Sized Thread Pool (which is basically sized through experimentation to give the best throughput), and then let the threads crunch away on the queue of tasks.

You will need a queue large enough to absorb all of your tasks, or you can look at something like the [NotifyingBlockingThreadPoolExecutor](https://github.com/USGS-CIDA/glri-afinch/blob/master/glri-afinch-util/src/main/java/org/java/util/concurrent/NotifyingBlockingThreadPoolExecutor.java). This will allow you to just gorge a queue and block when the queue gets to full, until all of your tasks are complete.

Addenda:

I don't know enough about Spring Boot to comment about whether a "batch job" would do what you want or not.

However, on that note, an alternative to creating 35,000 individual entries for the ExecutorService, you could, indeed, send a subset. For example 3,500 entries representing 10 items each, or 350 with 100 each. The idea there is to leverage any potential gains from reusing HTTP connections and what not, so there's less stand up and tear down for each request. Standing up 350 connections if far cheaper than standing up 35,000.

Comment: I was initially considering using a batch job for this. Do you think this will split it into threads?